# Redux-form's dispatch and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Currently came through an issue with properly typing `dispatch` function in redux-form.

`onSubmit` function from redux-form accepts two arguments:

```
const onSubmit = (values, dispatch) => {...};
```

However, it's not the exact same `dispatch` as this one from `redux`.

I mean, it looses typings. I can type it anyway I want and typescript wont throw any errors, e.g. `..., dispatch: Dispatch<{ foo: 'bar' }>)` even if there's no `foo` key anywhere in my component.

`Dispatch` type comes from `redux` and works fine if using `dispatch` with `connect`, e.g. in `mapDispatchToProps` function.

**Q**: How to type the `dispatch` function in redux-form properly?

#### Important:

When going to `Dispatch` initialization place, in `index.d.ts` file in `redux` node package, there's following interface:

```
export interface Dispatch<S> {
    <A extends Action>(action: A): A;
}
```

Why `S` is being omitted? Is it the reason why if I put anything as an argument for `Dispatch`, typescript accepts it?

Thanks!